# C++ framework для разработки NoSQL бд

Tags: c++, highload

Появилась необходимость написать свою базу данных. Существующий аналог на Java не устраивает чрезмерным потреблением памяти.
На си++ до этого писал только небольшие GUI-программки используя Qt.. 
Используя Qt очень удобно работать с массивами, списками, сетью, строками.. Там всё это хорошо задокументированно и код читается очень хорошо.. 
Будет ли разумно использовать Qt для создания кроссплатформенной высоконагруженной базы?

Comment: не думаю, что стоит этим заниматься, но если уж очень хочется, то смотрите в сторону boost и не смотрите в сторону Qt. Qt отличный GUI фрэймворк, в остальном он не так хорош, как может показаться. Кроме того, моё начальное понимание баз данных подсказывает мне, что там фреймворк не очень то и нужен. Нужно реализовать тонну структур данных и алгоритмов, зачем там фреймворк?

Comment: @otRock Думаю, что вопрос следует закрыть, так как это вопрос-опросник.

Comment: @ixSci спасибо!
пожалуй стоит закрыть, только я не знаю как)